# how to select a particular tag from seletected array of tags using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am selecting all  tags where href attribute is starting with "picThumbImgA_" as below.

`$('a[id^="picThumbImgA_"])')`

now i want to update some attributes of first four  tag. I can select first as

`$('a[id^="picThumbImgA_"]):first')`

and last as `$('a[id^="picThumbImgA_"]):last')` 
odd as `$('a[id^="picThumbImgA_"]):odd')`
and even as `$('a[id^="picThumbImgA_"]):even')`

But how can I process first four tags only.

Please help me out for the same.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/) function and exit the function by return false when you have processed the first 4.

```
$('a[id^="picThumbImgA_"])').each(function(index, el) {
    if(index < 4) {
        //do something
    } else {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try the Zero-based index selector `:lt()`, like :

```
$('a[id^="picThumbImgA_"]):lt(4)')
```

From [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/lt-selector/):

> Select all elements at an index less than index within the matched set.

You could also use `:nth-child()`, like:

```
$('a[id^="picThumbImgA_"]):nth-child(-n+4)')
```